# When will Ubuntu release an update to work flawlessly on Surface Pro 3?

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, surface, stable-release-updates

I wanted to load Ubuntu on my Surface Pro 3 but after some research have realized there are way too many issues. Such as WiFi unstable, type cover not working, Bluetooth stylus not fully functional, among others. Also, a long list of instructions just to install Ubuntu on Surface Pro 3. I understand there have been some progress on these issues but when will all this progress be included in the Ubuntu latest release, instead of trying to piece it together from all sorts of random sources. Surface Pro has been gaining momentum in the market and it would be nice to make the dual-boot a simple flawless process.

Comment: Honestly I don't expect to ever see one very soon, but there should be enough people interested that someone can create a bootable ISO with those problems already fixed.

Answer (score 3):

"Flawless" is subjective since not even Windows on the SP3 is without issues.  With 15.04, there is only one issue that I am concerned with, battery/suspend.  I basically never shut down.  I have a 1 hour commute to work by motorcycle and it never has an issue.  Uses about 10%/hr when just sitting idle.  I found you need to disable suspend completely in power manager, else it may try to suspend and result with a black screen (unlit).

The only thing you need to do is add the trackpad to X via evdev by editing /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf and adding this to the end:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Surface Pro 3 cover"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "evdev"
    Option "vendor" "045e"
    Option "product" "07dc"
    Option "IgnoreAbsoluteAxes" "True"
EndSection
```